# low disk space on filesystem root and LVM related

Tags: lvm

I'm a newbie in Linux, I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on oracle virtual box, while setting up Linux virtual machine, I've select dynamically allocated
I've allocated 10 GB space this VM
while installing some library or packages(that wasn't so big thou) I'm getting error like that "low disk space filesystem root"
then I've watched some videos on YouTube and there's a video on LVM
I've added 15 GB to virtual box first, then trying to add it to Linux and I guess without understanding I've created lvm2 of 16 GB and can't add it
in that video there's a command "vgdisplay" while I type it on command line no error nothing to show
I think may be there's no volume group to display, what will I do now
I mean I don't even know how partition works in ubuntu
cz while getting this type of msg on windows, I simply download any disk partition software and it automatically or easily I can add space to C drive from D drive
and I"m wondering is there anything or any type of software to do the same thing on Linux.. or actually what is LVM and how to I add space or something .... I just don't understand ...[long sigh]
can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS suggests a minimum of 25GB (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) but you've not stated if you were talking about Desktop or Server (which requires less, though both will vary on your intended use case). Your use of C: and D: is also confusing (Ubuntu doesn't have C: and D: drives), so I'm wondering if you have issues on your host which sounds like windows (given C: and D: references), which is off-topic here.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you were using C: and D: as example (as I said I'm lost by what you meant in your question), you can boot a 'live' system and use GUI tools too; in fact it's easier to make changes when the *filesystem* isn't in-use which occurs when using a 'live' system, but that's all setup on your unnamed host OS/virtualbox setup.